# Windows batch file syntax

Tags: windows, windows-7, batch-file

The following windows 7 batch file script returns the error:

```
@ECHO OFF

if exist C:\Program Files (x86)\ E1\P45V goto WIN7

ren /s /c "c:\Program Files\ E1\P45V\P45Login.bmp" "c:\Program Files\E1\P45V\P45Login_OLD.bmp"
copy "\\locattion14\temp\E1\P45Login.bmp" "c:\Program Files\ E1\P45V\P45Login.bmp"

goto END

:WIN7

ren /s /c "c:\Program Files (x86)\ E1\P45V\P45Login.bmp" "c:\Program Files (x86)\E1\P45V\P45Login_OLD.bmp"
copy "\\locattion14\temp\E1\P45Login.bmp" "c:\Program Files (x86)\ E1\P45V\P45Login.bmp"

:END
```

> The syntax of the command is incorrect

Using PSTOOLs to push out a change to computers, and will add the list when the syntax error is corrected.

The desired result:

If the pc is an XP machine, rename the P45login.bmp file to same name_OLD.bmp, then copy the file from loaction 14 into the directory noted.

If the PC is a Win 7 machine, skip the first part, go to the second part, and commit the same changes.

close the session.

I have moved quotes, added/subtracted switches, but arrive at the same error.

Surely it is just a simple syntax particularity that I am not catching.

Hoping someone will take a look, see the obvious I am missing, and point me in the right direction,.

Thank you for any help or suggestions.

Comment: I think "the following windows 7 batch file" is missing ...

Comment: Thank you! makes it a little easier then....?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ren` syntax is wrong. `ren` does not support any switches and also *rename_to* needs to be name only, not full path. See full details here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754276%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Additionally:
- `if exists` needs quotes around path
- you use both `\ E1\` or `\E1\` (with or without space). While both *could* be valid, I would double check if that's not an error.
- if the paths above are actually different, you need to use `move` (with full paths) instead of `ren`.